# What format is speech sent to cloud with Android speech recognition?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech

I'm building an app that includes speech recognition - I intend to use the Android speech recognition service or the voice typing functionality.

From what I have read, the speech is mostly processed in the cloud. The question I have is whether anyone knows what format the audio is sent to the cloud in? For example, is something like WAV or MP3 or PCM, or is it likely to be something else entirely?

I admit this is mostly out of plain curiosity to know a bit more of what is going on behind the scenes. (But partly it also relates to an interest in the impacts of pre and post processing on recognition.)

Answer (score 2):

Well , I've been looking for that info too , and the closest thing I could get to was the Google's [speech recognition API for chrome](http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/) which used [FLAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC) audio codec. I'm not sure if android uses it too, but it is the closest thing I ever get.